# Smoke (Explosion) Simulation Shading Displays Properly in Viewport Render, But Not In Final Render

Tags: texturing, smoke-simulation

The title more or less sums it up. I’ve simulated an explosion for a project that I’m working on. Out of seemingly nowhere, I can preview the explosion with all of its textures in the viewport but it just shows as regular smoke when I hit F12. I’ve attached some photos below, including the node setup for the explosion. Oddly, it did render just fine earlier today.

I’m an AMD user, so the first thing I checked was if the issue persists during CPU render and it does. I tried adjusting the number of cycles and light bounces, just kind of throwing anything at it. I do have some denouncing and glare set up in compositing but I was under the impression that that’s applied at the end of the render. Otherwise I can’t think of anything that would be causing this. The only things I (knowingly) changed in my scene today was adding a couple spot lights and adjusting the strength of my key light.

Any and all guidance would be deeply appreciated!

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Should you be using 'flame' for the input attribute, instead of 'heat'? All of the gas will have 'heat' but only the fire will have a positive 'flame'. I don't think this is your whole problem though...

Comment: That’s a good point and I did try out connecting flame to the factor of the bottom color ramp, but to no avail. This exact node setup worked earlier in the day. I dread having to bake the smoke simulation again but I’m almost positive it has to be something else.